# Invalid object name (table not found on renaming)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have renamed a table using

Exec sp_rename 'table1','dbo.table_new'

the table got renamed but when i do select * from dbo.table_new, its saying Invalid object name

but when i do select name,* from sysobjects where name like '%dbo.table_new%' i can see the object exists.

How do i view the table now ?Do i need some right ?

Comment: Check the last update now, and in the future don't use dbo. with sp_rename, just write the table name without dbo. because the default is dbo.

Answer (score 1):

because you should not write dbo. between '' because it will considered as string

now try write the following:

```
Exec sp_rename 'dbo.table_new','table_new'
```

it will work after that try selecting from the new table:

```
select * from Table_new
```

### Edit:

try:

```
EXEC sp_rename N'[dbo].[dbo.table_new]', N'table_new'
```

and be careful when you want to use dbo in the string put it between []

Comment: ya i tried its saying 
No item by the name of 'dbo.table_new' could be found in the current database 'db1'

Comment: if you write:
select name,* from sysobjects where name like 'dbo.table_new'
you can see the record?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get the red squigly lines under it when they shoudln't be there?

If so, Intellisense could do with a refresh:

```
  In Sql Server Mgnt Studio click Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache
```